# Handle environment-specific static files in Docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have created a nginx docker image:

```docker
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The relevant associated `nginx.conf` is:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www-dev.example.org;
    # would like: server_name ${WEBAPP_DOMAIN};

    # ...
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api-dev.example.org;
    # would like: server_name ${API_DOMAIN};

    # ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, the nginx instance serves multiple virtual hosts in the cluster, and each of them has a specific domain name which depends on the environment of the cluster (dev, staging, prod...).

The problem is that nginx does not support environment variables in the `server_name` directive. It only supports the `$hostname` variable, but I can't use that since I have multiple domain names in my case. I also can't use regular expressions (such as `~^www.+\.example\.org$`) because I have environments where the domain name does not follow any name construction rule (i.e. it might be `www.example2.com`).

I would like to avoid bulding a specific image for each environment (docker anti-pattern). How should I proceed then?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to achieve. Please show how it would looked like if Nginx supports environment variables in the server_name

Comment: There's at least a few options. You could mount a specific ``nginx.conf`` file into each container at run time or you could change the startup image command to first do a ``sed`` (or similar) to construct the ``nginx.conf`` file you want swapping values into the file from environment variables. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf for other options to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `envsubst`, which is included by default in the nginx Docker image, and as described in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) (section: "Using environment variables in nginx configuration"):

> By default, this function reads template files in `/etc/nginx/templates/*.template` and outputs the result of executing `envsubst` to `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

I just needed to modularize my config as such:

`compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    build: "."
    ports: "80:80"
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      - WEBAPP_DOMAIN=www-dev.example.org
      - API_DOMAIN=api-dev.example.org
```

`Dockerfile`

```docker
FROM nginx
COPY config/ /etc/nginx/
```

`config/nginx.conf`

```
#...
http {
  #...
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

`config/templates/webapp.conf.template`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name: ${WEBAPP_DOMAIN};
  #...
}
```

`config/templates/api.conf.template`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name: ${API_DOMAIN};
  #...
}
```